# EfficientAdapter and text format

Tags: android, listactivity

I am using EfficientAdapter that extends ListActivity.
For some reason, when I use code like:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text.setPadding((int) (Vars.screenWid-300), 30, 0, 30);
            if (position==1){
                holder.text.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
                holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            }else{
                holder.text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                 holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.text.setText(String.valueOf(Vars.DATAMIN[position]));
        return convertView;
    }
```

I get the list, but instead of just item 1 with Color.DKGRAY, I get it RANDOMALLY, on other items. I scroll up and down and see the background change from one item to another.
ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views are recycled(meaning you are setting the color of views that are going to show up in positions other than 1) so for that to work properly, you need to move the code where you change the padding and color based on position to outside of the `convertView == null` block.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    holder.text.setPadding((int) (Vars.screenWid-300), 30, 0, 30);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
if (position==1){
    holder.text.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
    holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
}else{
    holder.text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
holder.text.setText(String.valueOf(Vars.DATAMIN[position]));
```